# Where is the code for the Unity Container in the Composite Application Library?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm working with the Composite Application Library and I come across e.g. this line:

```
Shell shell = Container.Resolve<Shell>();
```

so I want to **look at the code that makes up the Resolve method**.

So I open up CompositeApplicationLibrary_Desktop.sln in Visual Studio.

I find classes such as UnityBootstrapper.cs, but **nowhere can I find the code for the UnityContainer class**. I find references to it such as:

```
UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
```

but if I rightclick on "UnityContainer()" and choose "go to definition" **all I get is meta data about this class**.

Where can I look at the code for the Resolve method on the UnityContainer class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also [download](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203104.aspx) just the Unity Application block.  There is a zip file in that   package that includes only Unity source.

The Resolve method can be found in there for sure (for example, that method calls DoBuildUp()...)

Comment: ok, I found that, executed it, it created files in c:\EntLib41Src, but there is no files called UnityContainer.cs and opening C:\EntLib41Src\Blocks\EnterpriseLibrary.sln in visual studio, I rightclick on "new UnityContainer()" and get meta data again. Where can the code be?

Comment: I added the download link for the Unity application block. I searched the source that comes with it and found the resolve method in there.